# Jquery - Select2 Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, plugins

Hi there i am using the select2-plugin in a search:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dropdown_users').select2({
            placeholder: 'Search for a category',
            ajax: {
                url: "search.php",
                dataType: 'json',
                quietMillis: 100,
                data: function (term, page) {
                    return {
                        term: term, //search term
                        page_limit: 10 // page size
                    };
                },
                results: function (data, page) {
                    return { results: data.results };
                }
            },
            initSelection: function(element, callback) {
                return $.getJSON("search?id=" + (element.val()), null, function(data) {
                        return callback(data);
                });
            }

    });
});
```

My question is:
When user select´s an option from the select, the selected data should be saved in a variable, like:

```
.onSelect: function() {
    var variable = $_GET['data'];
}
```

Is this possible?? Greetings!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#dropdown_users").on("select2-selecting", function(e) { 
     variable = e.val;
})
```

Note that this has been included in the 3.4 version.

Comment: this can be used as well: $('#dropdown_users').change(function() {

Comment: you could modify my code, so i can get images in my select as well?